# Change report definition in odoo

Tags: odoo

I try to change a report definition in a custom module but I do not succeed.

This is the report:

```
 <report
        id="account_invoices"
        model="account.invoice"
        string="Invoices"
        report_type="qweb-pdf"
        name="account.report_invoice"
        file="account.report_invoice"
        attachment_use="True"
        attachment="(object.state in ('open','paid')) and ('INV'+(object.number or '').replace('/','')+'.pdf')"
    />
```

and I want to remove the attachment_use property then I set

```
<report
    id="account_invoices"
    model="account.invoice"
    string="Invoices"
    report_type="qweb-pdf"
    name="account.report_invoice"
    file="account.report_invoice"
    attachment="(object.state in ('open','paid')) and ('INV'+(object.number or '').replace('/','')+'.pdf')"
/>
```

but instead of replacing the report, It creates a new one.
Is there a way to change this value ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just add **account** prefix to id. As like below. This the name of module, where report actually exist. This will not create new report and make changes in existing report.

```
<report
    id="account.account_invoices"
    model="account.invoice"
    string="Invoices"
    report_type="qweb-pdf"
    name="account.report_invoice"
    file="account.report_invoice"
    attachment_use="False"
    attachment="(object.state in ('open','paid')) and ('INV'+(object.number or '').replace('/','')+'.pdf')"
/>
```

Comment: it's seems invalid. If a change the string, nothing change :(

Comment: Have you upgraded the module after making above changes ?